# How do I set a global variable which can be changed through a command in discord

Tags: discord, discord.py

Not totally sure if I'm doing it correctly but here is the code:

```
dcoin = ""

@client.command()
async def ddraw(ctx, dcoin1):
  def check(m):
    return m.author.id == ddraw
  await ctx.send(dcoin1)

@client.command()
async def matches(ctx):  
  coin1 = "5"
  if coin1 == dcoin1:
    await ctx.send("Match")
  else:
    await ctx.send("Not a Match")
```

To my understanding, "dcoin1" is set to whatever is typed in the ddraw command which then changes the global variable of "dcoin1". Therefore it can check if it matches with the match command. (Used 5 as an example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `dcoin1` in `async def ddraw(ctx, dcoin1):` is an argument. It exists only in your function.

You can write this:

```py
dcoin = ""

@client.command()
async def ddraw(ctx, dcoin1):
    global dcoin
    dcoin = dcoin1
    await ctx.send(dcoin1)

@client.command()
async def matches(ctx):  
    coin1 = "5"
    if coin1 == dcoin:
        await ctx.send("Match")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Not a Match")
```

In this code `dcoin` is a global variable and users can modify it using `ddraw` command.

Comment: @gim Then could you accept my answer, please? (if it was helpful)